# Ubuntu is crashing/freezing (explained more in description)

Tags: ubuntu, kde

I have Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS with KDE Plasma.

Specs:

- Deepcool DQ850-M V2 800w powersuply
- Motherboard: X570 E GAMING ROG STRIX
- Processor: AMD RYZEN 9 5950X 16 CORE AND 32 THREADS
- RAM : RIPJAWS V 32GB 3600 MHZ (4 sticks total 128gb)
- AORUS 1TB NVME M.2 GEN4 - 5000MBPS
- RTX 3060 12GB DDR6 DUAL OC

From last 3 days, these are the things happening to my OS:

1.) Mostly I keep 4 chrome windows open (5-6 tabs in each window). So around every 30 minutes to 1 hour. One of the tab crash in a browser.

2.) Once or twice a day, my screen goes black and I get redirected to the login screen after 5 seconds, and after I Login, all windows/applications are closed.

3.) Sometimes Ubuntu also freezes (mouse works, but windows/taskbar etc are frozen, clicking anywhere does not work).

Should I reinstall my Ubuntu? If yes, how can I do it without deleting my files and Python enviornment? I am new to Ubuntu, i thought it will be better than windows. But idk how to fix this easily.

Comment: Check `/var/log/messages` and/or `dmesg` to help you identify the issue.

Comment: Does https://askubuntu.com/a/1492263/441847 answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Things to try:

0. If you're using Google Chrome (the proprietary binary) rather than Chromium (the open source version), then switch.
1. Install an ad-blocker and javascript controller in Chromium.  [uBlock Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm) (and uBO
   only - beware of forked versions) and [uMatrix](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/umatrix/ogfcmafjalglgifnmanfmnieipoejdcf) are good.  Both uBlock Origin and uMatrix are by Raymond Hill aka gorhill.

   Use uMatrix to disable javascript by default, only allow the bare minimum required to get particular sites working.  Use some of uMatrix's downloadable lists to block ad-ware, spyware, and other malware from all sites.   Same for uBlock Origin.
2. Try Firefox instead of Chromium.   uBlock Origin and uMatrix are also available for Firefox.  Install them.
3. Try a different desktop environment and see if your browser or your login session still crashes.  Perhaps Gnome, or something light-weight like xfce or lxde.
4. Check to see if you have the latest kernel available for Ubuntu 20.04, and the latest drivers for your GPU - even if you have to use a PPA to get an updated kernel or GPU driver.  If your GPU is nvidia, then the proprietary drivers are better.  If AMD or Intel, use the GPL drivers in the kernel.
5. Reinstalling Ubuntu is very unlikely to make any difference.   Upgrading to the latest Ubuntu (21.10) might.
6. Try powering off the system, opening it up and checking that the CPU, cooler, RAM, drives, GPU and any other expansion cards are properly seated.   Remove and re-install them to make sure.  Clean out any dust, preferably with a brush (artist's paint-brushes are good), a can of compressed air, and a mini vacuum cleaner.
7. Try removing half the RAM for a few days.  If the crashes go away, then you've got bad RAM.  If they don't, try again with the other half of the RAM.  If necessary, repeat with only one stick of RAM at a time, and with different combinations of RAM sticks.  Run `memtest86+` or `memtester`.
8. What kind and rating of PSU do you have?  Something decent and good enough for your system's power requirements (plus at least 20% on top of maximum draw)? Or just whatever cheap garbage your system builder could find for the least money?
9. What kind of ethernet controller?  Intel NICs are generally good.  Some models of some other brands (like Realtek) can be absolute garbage, with crappy drivers.
10. check to see if there is an updated BIOS (release version, not beta) for your motherboard.  Search forums for that vendor to see if anyone else is reporting the same problems (and if there are, whether there is a beta BIOS that claims to solve the problem - if so, it's probably worth risking a beta).
11. check if there are any updated firmware file for any of your hardware.  This may involve installing a newer version of `firmware-linux`, `firmware-linux-nonfree` or other firmware packages - perhaps from a PPA.

---

BTW, what kind of CPU, motherboard, and GPU do you have?   What kind of system?  Some name brand machine? or built from commodity parts either by yourself or by whoever you bought it from?

Name brand machines are almost always crap, designed for corporate peons to run Word & Excel, and to be "serviced" by corporate IT drones who generally aren't capable of more than calling the vendor to come and replace the hardware when something goes wrong.

OTOH, machines built from commodity parts can vary greatly.  Some are great if good hardware was selected and it was built competently.  Some are garbage. Most are at least OK.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. Firefox also crash. Just now I checked I get this error when chrome tab crashes "Error code: SIGSEGV"

Comment: Here are the specs of my desktop https://drive.google.com/file/d/13mvcvmlWVoQMP2ctBS23zipeEJgEmn_R/view?usp=sharing

Comment: do firefox/chromium crash while watching videos? or on any web page?   do you have an ad blocker and javascript blocker installed?  if not, then that's the first thing you should do.  Otherwise, your machine will run any random code that any web site you visit (or the ad services used by that site) tells it to run.  This is not good for system stability.  or security. or privacy. etc.     The segfault increases my suspicion that you have some kind of hardware fault (probably RAM) but doesn't entirely eliminate a software fault.

Comment: please don't post links to third party sites.  edit your question and post anything relevant there. no images, just text.

Comment: I think they crash mostly on a stock market website (they get a lot of prices every 0.5 second). No adblocked or any extension installed.

Comment: I will try point 6 first, If its related to RAM. Thanks a lot. Editing the question also

Comment: Install uBO and uMatrix.  The problem will probably go away.   Depending on what specific site(s) you're visiting, you may need to spend a few minutes enabling and disabling javascript from specific sources in umatrix to get the site working.

Comment: Thanks will do. Can Chrome/Firefox webpage scripts also make the whole system crash multiple times? Since Ubuntu is also crashing from time to time since last 3 days.

Comment: Yes, malware spread by web pages can crash systems.  Browser makers make a decent effort to make this harder to do, but their interests are not your interests. They (especially google) make money by selling ads and running spyware so their efforts are compromised by their own needs to run bad code. The only way to be reasonably safe is to not run code from web sites unless a) you trust the site, at least to a limited degree and b) you only allow the minimum js required for the site to function correctly (this generally means blocking third-party tracking, ad-ware, and other crap).

Comment: Having trouble accessing my old account. Anyway, I formatted my hard disk and installed Ubuntu 21.04. Still getting same problem. I guess, its time to get into hardware. Will try to remove RAM first. I was a bit afraid to touch hardware, since I am newbie. Will let you know, how it goes. Thank you

Comment: @cas So I got like 200+ error after running memtest86. Then I removed two ram sticks, and got 0 error. Then inserted 1 ram stick (total 3 now), got 0 error. Then inserted 4th ram stick, again 0 error. So  I guess, removing the ram stick and reinserting it fixed the problem. Weird. Thanks a lot

Sorry unable to access that account, so cant mark it as correct answer.

Comment: it's not that uncommon for ram sticks to be almost-but-not-quite inserted correctly.  you actually have to push down hard when installing them, until you hear them click into place.  usually, though, they don't work at all when not inserted correctly.  maybe there was dust in the socket. or something.   more generally, loose or barely adequate connections are a fairly common source of intermittent hardware errors.  removing and reinstalling the device can often fix this kind of fault.